# Newly Imaged SurfacePro - Can't Connect to this Network Error

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a SurfacePro that has been imaged and when attempting to connect to the network with the correct credentials I get the "Can't connect to this network" error.

I have reimaged the device 2 more times to see if that would work still running into the same issue.

Can anyone else point me as to how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you updated the device drivers for your devices?

Comment: @BigChris Drivers for Network adapters are all up to date. Please advise.

Comment: Did you use the same image each time you re-imaged the machine.  Perhaps its a bad image?

Comment: Try turning Windows Firewall off, disable any third-party firewall (McAfee etc.), try `netsh wlan int ip reset`, try turning off encryption to your wireless network, try turning off IPv6 for the adapter... lots to try.